# Scroll down to bottom of page with iMacros

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, raspberry-pi, imacros

I'm running an iMacro in Iceweasel (Firefox) on my Raspberry Pi. However, I can't seem to get it to scroll down to the bottom of the page. This is what I am currently using (and it isn't working):

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Your<SP>Tasks
URL GOTO=javascript:window.scrollBy(0,20000)
```

The first line of the code clicks a button in order to navigate to a new webpage. The second line is meant to scroll down to the bottom of the page, but doesn't.

Comment: @freestock.tk I'm using iMacros and I'm on a Raspberry Pi...

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to set `!WAITPAGECOMPLETE` to `YES` and then use `URL GOTO` instead of just clicking on the button with `TAG`. This means that the new page will be loaded before the javascript is executed.

```
SET !WAITPAGECOMPLETE YES
URL GOTO=https://example.com
URL GOTO=javascript:window.scrollBy(0,20000)
```

Comment: @macroscripts yes, it works perfectly, although I am a bit annoyed that it doesn't work with just clicking on the button. I think that iMacros should be able to detect when a button click takes one to a new page. However, it doesn't and even with `!WAITPAGECOMPLETE YES` using `TAG` causes iMacros to execute the Javascript on the previous page.

Comment: This does not work if you have no scroll on the target page or are already scrolled to bottom, and have SET !WAITPAGECOMPLETE YES enabled. It will hang forever. javascript will also not allow if with else, closures, methods, or voids, so no way to break the 'indefinite hang'. The only real option is to upgrade to later version of iMacros and use 'end' key press instead with: EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR=* KEY=35